# How can I undo the command # and * of VIM

Tags: vim, neovim

Once I got the word with `#` or `*` how can go backward that command to not highlight the words.

Comment: This command doesn't has anything to undo, i belive.

Comment: See `:help jumplist` and the commands `:help CTRL_O` and it's counterpart `:help CTRL_I`. To toggle highlighting, you can put this in your .vimrc: `nnoremap <silent> <expr> <LEADER>/ (v:hlsearch ? ':nohls' : ':set hls')."\n"`

Comment: CTRL_O to undo the cursor movement. `/lkj;l;kj` to undo the highlighting.

Comment: `:nohlsearch` is probably the "correct" way to turn off the highlighting, but searching for a random string works, too.

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal, here?

If you want to go back to the previous match, then you could use `*` after a `#` or `#` after a `*`, or maybe `:help ctrl-o` as a direction-agnostic alternative.

If you want to stay where you are but disable the search highlighting, then the proper way is to use `:help :nohlsearch`. This is sadly cumbersome and there is no built-in way to do that automatically so vimmers have come up with *many* workarounds like the one suggested by @mattb in the comments. There are also a couple of plugins for that.